# p4 filesystem size error && unable to move P4ROOT in Unix ans such

Tags: filesystems, perforce

As in the screen capture my initial p4d setup was a bit off and I just realized it when p4 & p4v start screaming file system on my server is lacking space. I'm currently shut off from p4v in client and p4 in PuTTY.

Current p4 and P4LOG directories are not what I intended to set, the intention was to have depot in the volume with 3.5T, but instead I messed up by sticking it in /var/log and such.

To overcome this mess I tried changing P4ROOT and P4LOG as sudo to the volume I originally created, but couldn't as p4 told me:

> Can't set registry on UNIX

Hoped setting it up as p4 was off and tried `p4 admin stop`, still no luck.

[image: Current status in Unix with PuTTY]

Comment: Make a brand new server, in the correct location, and then use `p4 fetch` and `p4 push` to copy the files and changelists that you've already submitted from the old server to the new server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop the server by doing a "kill" on the p4d process.  Since nobody's able to run any commands right now this is perfectly safe.

Once the server is stopped, move your P4ROOT directory and your P4LOG file to locations that have adequate space.

Then you can restart your server with the correct settings:

```
p4d -r /correct/root/location -L /correct/logfile/location
```

If you normally start p4d via some sort of script that uses the old locations, make sure to update that too (and/or update your environment variables, etc).

Comment: Thanks! I'm still struggling but your tip gave me some progress and put me back on good track!

However, p4a & p4v still gives me filesystem P4JOURNAL has only xxx free error.
Where I'm now : p4 set shows me correct and new directories for P4ROOT, P4LOG, P4JOURNAL, but the error message above still occurs.

Comment: Sounds like you need to relocate P4JOURNAL as well.  That's the -J flag to p4d.

Comment: Done and good!
Big thanks to you!
Another thing I've learned and won't forget.

I'm still learning things and still really weak at basic operations with p4v streams depot. p4ignore reads correct p4ignore file i've linked as enviro to, but when I do initial project upload (also even when I do normal submit sometimes) to my mainline streams it just omits my p4ignore and library gets up there as well. It's pain in the butt and I think I'm getting something wrong about using it correctly.